# First child selector doesn't work if header is present

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple HTML with an header and some sections.

```
<header>Header</header>
<section>Section 1</section>
<section>Section 2</section>
<section>Section 3</section>
```

I would like to style the first section

```
section:first-child {
    background-color:green;    
}
```

It seems that the `:first:child` selector doesn't work when `header` is present ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk2Dg/1/)). When I remove `header` everything works again! Why?

Comment: For old browsers, `.parent > section:first-child, .parent > header:first-child + section`

Answer (score 5):

That's because the `<section>` is not the first child of its parent.

[`element:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) represents the **first child** of its parent, matching the element. And in your case, the first element of the parent is a `<header>` element.

You could use `:first-of-type` pseudo-class instead.

```css
section:first-of-type {
    background-color:green;    
}
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type):

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.

Answer (score 2):

you should apply `first-of-type`.

```
section:first-of-type {
    background-color:green;    
}
```

Comment: You beat me just 2 sec. Amazing.

Comment: @HashemQolami Your answer was very explanatory however good job!

Answer (score 1):

should try `:first-of-type` psuedo class

```
section:first-of-type {
    background-color:green;    
}
```