# Resolving overlap between fixed header and first section

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

I am coding up a landing page with the classical setup :

- A fixed header
- Several sections (product description, testimonials, google map, etc.)
- A footer

My semantics look like this :

```html
<header>
  <!-- Responsive navigation bar -->
</header>
<section class="section-first">
  <!-- First section -->
</section>
<section>
</section>
...
<footer>
</footer>
```

As the header is fixed, I need a specific CSS treatment on the *first* section, as such :

```css
.section-first {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

so that the header and the first section do not overlap. So eventually my first section needs to be treated differently than others. My current approach seems like a tweak to me, there should be either a semantical way to approach this or a clean CSS market practice in such common situation. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you use classes/ids ? Or you can just specify the position and adjust it's  location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `:first-of-type` pseudo element!

```
section:first-of-type{
    margin-top:200px;
}
```

This finds the first `section` tag in your HTML without having to add an extra class to it and only applies the written styles to that one.

Comment: I think you meant :first-of-type. This less snippet did exactly the job :

    header {
 top:0;
 position: fixed;
    }

    section {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 &:first-of-type {
  margin-top:200px;
 }
    }
Thanks :)

Comment: No, I meant :first-child. I guess the wording is a little confusing. This will look at the HTML doc and select the first child of the HTML tag that is labeled 'section'.

Comment: Ok. Actually I wanted the `section` tag to have a specific `margin-top` (as in the code sample provided in the question).

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding your question wrong. This gives the first section tag whatever specific css you want. In this case, a margin top of 200px, like you stated above. It will only apply to the first element. So this would be a cleaner approach than adding a class to the element like you have above.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297326/first-child-selector-doesnt-work-if-header-is-present) should clarify what I have experienced using `first:child`

Comment: Learn something new each day! Thank YOU!

Comment: jleggio : could you modify your post accordingly ? Thanks